# Are specific mod-making questions allowed?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I'm sorry for my english.

This is more of a specific question, since I'm not sure if here is fully allowed to ask these kind of technical questions.

Say for example I want to modify Starcraft, so I ask things like "how to make SCVs fire burst lasers?", "Make regenerate health points faster?", "is there a way to modify the way shield points regenerate?" or "what's the deal with the 'white circle (Invisible)' thing?", and so on...

IMO, these should be inside of a mod-making Q&A site, rather than a general gaming Q&A, since is more an editing question. But neither in gamedev, since I'm not actually programming from a source code or anything, it's more like being teached: how to use third party programs to do whatever you ever wanted to do or make happen, but inside of a particular game.

I'm not sure if I've been clear about the question: Are we all able to ask technical/specific mod-making questions like this? Or should I propose a new Q&A site in StackExchange about it?