# Are questions about Skyrim's creation kit allowed here/on-topic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I have not seen any questions about the creation kit and this makes me wonder if these types of questions are allowed here?

The creation kit is technically a separate program but it is used specifically for one game.

I have searched on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) but there seems to be very little activity for it.

Comment: I believe questions about this would probably be fine, though I don't expect there to be a hotbed of question activity for it here, either.

Comment: @RavenDreamer Questions perhaps not, but answers; yes! (i think). - A lot of Skyrim players on pc use mods, either their own or downloaded ones. And from what i understand, the creation kit was also present in previous elder scroll games.

Comment: @RavenDreamer the creation kit is solely for mod development, this http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/7937/are-specific-mod-making-questions-allowed?rq=1 would say they are off-topic.

Comment: Hmm...the linked meta post is a duplicate, the post it's a duplicate of is a bit more split...there are (at present) two equally upvoted answers, on of them "if it only involves editing game files, and not heavy programming, it's fine here", with the other being that these would be better on game dev or stack overflow. I know I've seen at least one question that falls on the light end of game file editing that felt to me like it very much belongs here, and might be a bit out-of-place at game dev or stack overflow, since it's about the files of a specific game.

Comment: Which is to say, I think this question doesn't necessarily have a clear-cut answer based on previous meta discussions. "Would the questions feel at home in this community?" is one test that must be passed; we could also consider whether it's important to not split the questions between the two sites, and if so, in which community these questions would feel most at home, and receive the best answers.

Comment: As a game developer, I would not ask a gamer anything to do with the actual development. I would be asking a lot of questions, but they would all be to gauge reception and judge an opinion. I feel this should not be ontopic, here. However, the leading argument is that game dev SE is such a better fit for these type of questions. Direct users where they are more likely to get an answer. That said, I initially thought the same thing about some of the minecraft questions.

Comment: Also, just had a look, and they at least have a skyrim editor tag

Comment: Should i add an answer to this thread; based off of the comments made here or do these type of questions usually go unanswered? i don't post on the meta often

Comment: @Jim, [I believe you did not look hard enough](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-creation-kit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like the kind of thing that might've been on topic here, if there wasn't somewhere better already.

There are already [questions about the Skyrim Creation Kit](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-creation-kit) on GameDev SE, as Timelord64 pointed out. There's also a [meta question](https://gamedev.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/58/do-mod-and-map-making-questions-belong-here) on their meta about these kind of questions, indicating that they are on topic.

We also have meta questions ([1](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/562/108003),[2](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7937/108003)) here that generally agree that it doesn't seem like a good fit, as Kevin van der Velden pointed out.