# Suggest removal of tag synonym (The Elders Scrolls Construction Kit)

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

There are two tags for questions about the TES Construction Kit, namely 
`tes-construction-set` and (the presumed master tag) `the-elder-scrolls-construction-Set`. 

The first tag has zero questions, and the second an impressive three.

I'm not sure whether we need these at all, since questions about modding tend to be off-topic, but [that matter](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11180/are-questions-about-skyrims-creation-kit-allowed-here-on-topic) has been addressed before.

All three aforementioned Construction Set questions are ..questionable in their on-topicness: [one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/298507/help-with-morrowinds-construction-set) is about the direct in-game impact of a change made in the editor, [one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/346590/oblivion-tes-construction-set-self-made-landscape-patch-not-working) about a self-made patch to resolve compatibility between two mods, and [one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/215041/tes-construction-set-import-an-external-mod) about being unable to open a native `.esp` file in the Creation Kit.

For questions regarding the modding of Fallout 3, Fallout: New vegas, and Fallout 4, the general tag `mods` is used.

Assuming tags for specific editors of specific games is convenient, we might need to add `Creation Kit` for Skyrim and Fallout 4, and `G.E.C.K.` for Fallout 3 and fallout: New Vegas.

Comment: I believe you mean `construction-set` rather than `construction-kit`. And FWIW, the questions you are referring to were recently modified to update the tag from `tes-construction-set` to `the-elder-scrolls-construction-set` within the last day

Comment: @Wondercricket You're right about both things: I changed my post, and remember seeing the three posts having been edited (I didn't check to see what was edited). That was done for this very reason?

Comment: Ever since the tag char increase, a lot of users have been doing generally tag clean up. If I remembered correctly, unused tags will eventually go away anyways. As far as keeping the tag as a whole and the on-topicness, I’ll leave the discussions to those who are more mod-savy :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The tag [tes-construction-set] will be automatically removed

Here is what happened:

1. All three questions were tagged with [tes-construction-set](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tes-construction-set)

   - This was probably created before the tag name limit was increased from 25 characters to 35 characters
2. Noticing that [every other game in the series is tagged with the prefix](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim+or+the-elder-scrolls-online+or+the-elder-scrolls-4-oblivion+or+the-elder-scrolls-3-morrowind+or+the-elder-scrolls-series+or+the-elder-scrolls-arena+or+the-elder-scrolls-2-daggerfall+or+the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim-vr+or+the-elder-scrolls-construction-set+or+the-elder-scrolls-legends) `the-elder-scrolls`, I went ahead and changed the questions to instead be tagged with [the-elder-scrolls-construction-set](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-construction-set)

   - A mod has to get involved to create tag synonyms because the synonym creation process is [fundamentally flawed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/204244/191265)), and that didn't happen here
3. Now no more questions were tagged with [tes-construction-set](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tes-construction-set)

The system automatically deletes tags with no questions after about 24 hours. So that will resolve itself automatically.

Whether or not questions *should* be tagged specifically for *The Elder Scrolls Construction Set* is a different matter best served in another discussion. If the decision were made to remove it, then when there are no questions tagged with [the-elder-scrolls-construction-set](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-construction-set), that too will be deleted after about 24 hours.

Comment: Thanks. I knew this - the automatic removal - was the case for questions, but didn't know it worked the same for tags. A lack of research on my part. I guess this question is superfluous, then, and I shall remove it.